# Edit linux environmental variables using bash

Tags: linux, bash, vi

I want to edit an environmental variable, namely no_proxy. It is very long already. Similar to how the current command in bash can be opened in vi or another editor by pressing ctrl +x,ctrl +e. Is there a way to open an environmental variable in vi then save it.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need, but just for the current shell session.

```
echo $VARNAME > /tmp/VARNAME;vi /tmp/VARNAME; export VARNAME=`cat /tmp/VARNAME`
```

If you want to change the environment variable value permanently, you should find where it is declared and change it there.

Comment: this is pretty good thanks, I was going to add this as a script in /usr/local/bin

as something like editvar

just pseudo code at the minute 

#!/bin/bash
VARNAME=$1
echo $$VARNAME > /tmp/$VARNAME;$EDITOR /tmp/$VARNAME; export $VARNAME=`cat /tmp/$VARNAME`

Comment: #!/bin/bash
VARNAME=$1
echo ${!VARNAME} > /tmp/$VARNAME;$EDITOR /tmp/$VARNAME;eval export $VARNAME=`cat /tmp/$VARNAME`

Comment: seems i can't export that var out of the script

Comment: Use `source scriptname` to run the command in your current shell.

Comment: I can't source that script and input the variable name; source editvar HOME
editvar:3: bad substitution

Comment: Please paste here your script content, I can't see where you assign HOME

Comment: export $VARNAME=cat /tmp/$VARNAME should be export VARNAME=$(cat /tmp/$VARNAME). For command substitution use backticks or $(command) notation

Comment: #!/bin/bash VARNAME=$1; echo ${!VARNAME} > /tmp/$VARNAME;$EDITOR /tmp/$VARNAME;eval export $VARNAME=``cat /tmp/$VARNAME``

Comment: @franzisk Just added my script above

Comment: Your last export command has a syntax error, you should remove the $ sign in $VARNAME.
`VARNAME=something (assign a value to a variable)`
`echo $VARNAME`(use the variable value)

Comment: ➜  ~ bash -x editvars HOME  
+ VARNAME=HOME  
+ echo /home/ronan  
+ vi /tmp/HOME  
++ cat /tmp/HOME  
+ eval export HOME=/home/ronan/.ssh  
++ export HOME=/home/ronan/.ssh  
++ HOME=/home/ronan/.ssh  
➜  ~ echo $HOME  
/home/ronan

Comment: Above is the script running I couldn't add the line breaks, it does assign the variable the way I want, but the export command is run in a child shell so my current shell doesn't inherit it